# Difference in @@session.time_zone value between mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have issue in reading @@session.time_zone value in PHP.

when i run :

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

in mysql client i get the value i have set in mysql configuration: **+03:00**

but when i run this query in PHP i get **+00:00** , even i set the timezone in php.ini `date.timezone = "Asia/Riyadh"` which is **+03:00**

any idea?

Comment: The PHP timezone has nothing to do with the MySQL timezone.

Comment: but @@session.time_zone is a mysql value . and reading it via PHP returns wrong value.

Comment: my concern is to get timestamp values from database in php correctly . currently php is getting it in "+00:00" timezone instead of "+03:00"

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? If you use PDO, it has an option `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` which allows you to specify a default query to execute. This is often used to set the timezone.

Comment: Why  you don't save everything in utc and then convert it back in php, so you dpn't have to care which timezone  was used